# onMetadataChanged MediaControllerCompat.Callback never called

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-mediasession

I'm developing a simple Audio Player app for a radio station.
I have successfully made a `MediaBrowser` and registered a callback to listen for `playBack`- or `metadata` changes.

```
var mediaBrowser : MediaBrowserCompat by Delegates.notNull()
mediaBrowser = MediaBrowserCompat(
        activity,
        ComponentName(activity, MediaPlaybackService::class.java),
        object : MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback() {
            override fun onConnected() {
                val mediaController = MediaControllerCompat(activity, mediaBrowser.sessionToken)
                MediaControllerCompat.setMediaController(activity, mediaController)
                mediaController.registerCallback(ControllerCallback)
                mediaControllerFunc()
            }
        },
        null
)

object ControllerCallback : MediaControllerCompat.Callback() {
    override fun onMetadataChanged(metadata: MediaMetadataCompat) {
        //TODO: Never called
    }

    override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(state: PlaybackStateCompat) {
        //Called
    }
}
```

The `playback` changes are received when I call

```
mediaSession.setPlaybackState(
    PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)
            .setState(STATE_PLAYING, DEFAULT_PLAYBACK_POSITION, DEFAULT_PLAYBACK_SPEED)
            .build()
)
```

However metadata changes are not.
Even though I call

```
mediaSession.setMetadata(
    MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
        .putLong(METADATA_KEY_DURATION, -1)
        .putString(METADATA_KEY_TITLE, title)
        .putString(METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, artist)
        .putBitmap(METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, albumCover)
        .putString(METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI, albumCoverUrl)
        .build()
)
```

What am I missing to receive metadata changes?
If it can help the complete repository is available on [Github](https://github.com/timrijckaert/topradio-android-client)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution for anybody experiencing the same problem.

It turned out I was mixing `compat` (service layer responsible for starting the audio service and connection to metadata) and non `compat` (UI layer) variants of the API.

In particular the activity.
Since I am targeting Lollipop and higher I decided to use `Activity` instead of the `AppCompatActivity`.

This apparently silently breaks the `MediaControllerCompat.Callback` for `onMetadataChanged()`, but not for `onPlaybackStateChanged()`.
Can't seem to find why?!

In code it is as simple as changing:

`class PlayableActivity : Activity() { ... }`

to:

`class PlayableActivity : AppCompatActivity() { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

`onPlaybackStateChanged` properly works for support library before version 26 for me. Since then, I cannot make it trigger this specific callback at all. `onMetadataChanged` works properly after force update on `onConnected()`. Everything is of `Comppat` type. 
I looked into the source and in the case of `onPlaybackStateChanged`, it relies on some `ExtraCallback` which never gets triggered:

```
  @Override
        public void onPlaybackStateChanged(Object stateObj) {
            MediaControllerCompat.Callback callback = mCallback.get();
            if (callback != null) {
                if (callback.mHasExtraCallback) {
                    // Ignore. ExtraCallback will handle this.
                } else {
                    callback.onPlaybackStateChanged(
                            PlaybackStateCompat.fromPlaybackState(stateObj));
                }
            }
        }
```

I am not sure if it is related, but this `ExtraCallback` is weakly referenced so it might happen that it is being lost and collected.

Comment: Even am facing the same issue where if register callback at two places only onPlaybackStateChanged() is called only at first place and not again. Prior to this with 25.4.0 it used to work properly. Let me know if you were able to fix it in anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've registered callback for `MediaControllerCompat`, but never call `onPlaybackStateChanged(mMediaController.getPlaybackState())`
[as in sample here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaBrowserService/blob/ed830016fdf702c65698924b5d617d496e08606e/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/mediasession/client/MediaBrowserAdapter.java#L177)